# Writing a polynomial in facorized form in Java

Tags: java, math, polynomials

So I have an array of coefficients of complex numbers. So if c= a+ib, a coefficient would be stored as (a,b). My array is called Coeff[i]. I'd like to write a function which would accept a variable, say z, and evaluate the polynomial. But the thing is, I don't want to use Math.Pow function I'd like to evaluate the polynomial like this:

[image]

I have tried writing down polynomials of degree 1,2,3,4 and by this I noticed a pattern(i mean it's kind of obvious). But then I could not think of a way of writing it that way. If anyone could help that would be great.

Maybe I should set up a loop that would start from the highest index and sum up the polynomial from inwards?

I think I have to set up a loop with these, but I'm not sure how to exactly: [image]

Comment: What language are you using?  Also, if you have tried something, it would be useful to see it posted here.

Comment: So that approach looks correct; I've offered a suggestion below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing is called [Hormer's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method) for evaluating polynomials.  You can evaluate by starting at the highest order term and then repeatedly multiply it by z and then add the next highest order term, rinse repeat.  It looks something like this:

```
Complex eval(Complex z, Complex coeff[]) {
  Complex eval = 0;

  for (int i = coeff.length-1; i > 0; i--) {
    eval += Complex.add(coeff[i], Complex.mul(eval, z));
  }

  return eval + coeff[0];
}
```

You would need to do some validation on the inputs (i.e. make sure the array isn't empty), and this assumes you have a class for manipulating complex numbers (I don't recall if there's a standard one available).  Also, I haven't tested this, so take it with a grain of salt, but this is the general idea.

Comment: just out of curiousity, did you see my previous question? Because you're using the same method complex.add and complex.mul https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60418436/setting-up-array-of-complex-coefficients-avoiding-the-leading-zeros

Comment: @user6969 No, I didn't see that other question; I'll take a look at it.  The names Complex.add and Complex.mul would seem to be the obvious choices for complex number libraries in Java (where operator overloading isn't allowed).